# Can't pass 'checked' state and custom parameter in QMenu items to connected slot

Tags: python, pyside2

I've created a `QMenu` and added a number of checkable `QAction` items to the menu. All of these items connect to the same slot function.

If a checkable `QAction` is clicked, the `triggered` signal is emitted and the status of the check-mark [is passed as an argument](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-5/PySide2/QtWidgets/QAction.html#PySide2.QtWidgets.PySide2.QtWidgets.QAction.triggered) to the connected slot function.

In the slot function I want to distinguish between the clicked items. I tried to do that by passing an index to the slot function using a lambda , in addition to passing the `checked` state.

The only thing I can't achieve is to have both the `checked` state and my index passed to the slot function.

See example code below. The different variants of the `slot` variable in the example shows what I've tried so far.

```
import sys
from PySide2 import QtCore
from PySide2.QtWidgets import (QMainWindow, QApplication, QAction)

class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        # create menu
        self.dynamic_menu = self.menuBar().addMenu('tools')
        # add menu items
        labels = ['tool0', 'tool1', 'tool2']
        for index, label in enumerate(labels):
            # passes 'checked' correctly, but 'index' is always 2 (last loop value)
            # slot = lambda checked: self.run_menu_item(checked, index)
            #
            # Throws exception:
            #   TypeError: <lambda>() missing 1 required positional argument: 'checked'
            # slot = lambda checked, i=index: self.run_menu_item(checked, i)
            #
            # passes 'checked' always as False, but index is correct
            slot = lambda checked=False, i=index: self.run_menu_item(checked, i)

            action = QAction(label, self)
            action.triggered.connect(slot)
            action.setCheckable(True)
            self.dynamic_menu.addAction(action)
            
    @QtCore.Slot(bool, int)
    def run_menu_item(self, checked, index):
        print('checked:{} index:{}'.format(checked, index))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.setMinimumSize(400, 100)
    print('starting app...')
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

How can I define `slot` so I get both the `checked` state of the menu item and also the correct index as parameters to my slot function `run_menu_item`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since [`triggered`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qaction.html#triggered) is an overload signal, then the signature must be pointed out: `action.triggered[bool].connect(slot)`.

```py
class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        # create menu
        self.dynamic_menu = self.menuBar().addMenu("tools")
        # add menu items
        labels = ["tool0", "tool1", "tool2"]
        for index, label in enumerate(labels):
            slot = lambda checked, i=index: self.run_menu_item(checked, i)
            action = QAction(label, self)
            action.triggered[bool].connect(slot)
            action.setCheckable(True)
            self.dynamic_menu.addAction(action)

    @QtCore.Slot(bool, int)
    def run_menu_item(self, checked, index):
        print("checked:{} index:{}".format(checked, index))
```

Comment: Works as a charm. Could you please point me to the Python docs where the signature syntax (`triggered[bool]`) is explained?

Comment: @NZD I don't know if PySide2 has it documented but PyQt5 does: https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/signals_slots.html#connecting-disconnecting-and-emitting-signals